# Create Account Object

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program creates an Account object with an account id of 1122, a balance of $20,000, and an annual interest rate of 4.5%. It uses the withdraw method to withdraw $2,500, the deposit method to deposit $3,000, and print the id, balance, monthly interest rate, and monthly interest.

I am having problems with the next part which is that my program should also ask for the starting values for id, balance, and interest rate. Then it should present a menu where a user can modify their account. After each selection an appropriate message should be displayed. The menu should then be displayed again.

Example Menu:

> (1): Display ID
>
> (2): Display Balance
>
> (3): Display Annual Interest Rate
>
> (4): Display Monthly Interest Rate
>
> (5): Display Monthly Interest
>
> (6): Withdraw Money
>
> (7): Deposit Money
>
> (8): Exit

How can I modify my code to function properly with the user input? Right now it is working, but I don't have any code that asks the user for input.

This is the code that I have:

```
main module:

from Account import Account

def main():
    updatedAccount = Account(1122,20000,4.5)
    updatedAccount.withdraw(2500)
    print("User ID : ", updatedAccount.id)
    print("Beginning Balance: ", updatedAccount.balance)
    print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", updatedAccount.monthly_interest_rate)
    print("Monthly Interest: ", updatedAccount.get_monthly_interest())

main()
```

Account.py

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self, id, initial_balance=0, rate=4.5):
        self.id = id
        self.balance = initial_balance
        self.annual_interest_rate = rate

    @property
    def monthly_interest_rate(self):
        return self.annual_interest_rate / 12

    def get_monthly_interest(self):
        return self.balance * self.monthly_interest_rate

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance < amount:
            raise ValueError(f"Overdraft, balance less than {amount}")

        self.balance -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance +=amount
```

I have tried writing user input for the starting account values, but I am having trouble using it to create the Account object and how to implement the menu.

```
userid = float(input("Enter User ID: "))
InterestRate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate: "))
balance = float(input("Enter balance: "))

print("User ID is: ", userid)
print("Interest Rate: ", InterestRate)
print("Balance is: ", balance)
```

Comment: Basically you're going to need to, in a loop, (1) display the menu options, (2) read the user's selection, (3) do what the user asked.  This is fairly broad--I would suggest trying the above and editing the post if more specific questions arise, or if you have code for a menu and can specifically indicate how its behavior is different from what you're wanting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user the constructor of `Account` and provide the values you have

```
userid = float(input("Enter User ID: "))   // maybe use int() rather than float ? 
interestRate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate: "))
balance = float(input("Enter balance: "))

acc = Account(userid, balance, interestRate)

print(acc)
```

If you override the `__str__` method you can print the object just by calling `print(acc)`

```
// in Account class
def __str__(self):
    return f"ID {self.id},Bal {self.balance}, Rat {self.annual_interest_rate}"
```

---

A simple way for the menu can be this, complete the `if/elif` code in the `apply_actions` and ad them in the same order in the `actions` array

```
def apply_actions(action, account):
    if action == 0:      # display ID
        print(f"Your id is {account.id}")
    elif action == 1:    # display balance
        print(f"Your balance is {account.balance}")
    # ...
    elif action == 6:
        to_deposit = float(input("How many money for the deposit ?"))
        account.deposit(to_deposit)
    elif action == 7:
        exit(1)
    else:
        print("Bad index")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
    acc = Account(userid, balance, interestRate)

    actions = ["Display ID", "Display Balance", "Deposit", "Exit"]
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Choose index in " + str(list(enumerate(actions)))))
        apply_actions(choice, acc)
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example of how to start my menu?

Comment: @LouisS. I've edited to add a small example, but if you need more, you may think about trying to do it and then create a new question on SO because this is a differnt purpose

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions, regarding account creation, you do it normally using user input.

```py
userid = float(input("Enter User ID: "))
InterestRate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate: ")) 
balance = float(input("Enter balance: "))

user_account = Account(userid, balance, InterestRate)
```

Now, for your menu, you can create a simple function displaying your menu and sending user to each function and when user is done send them back to your menu.

```py
def menu():
    possibilities = [(1, "Display ID", "id"), (2, "Display balance", "balance")]
    while True:
        for possibility in possibilities:
            print(f"({possibility[0]}): {possibility[1]}")
        User_input = int(input("Please select an option"))
         if User_input in [pos[0] for pos in possibilities]:
              option, name, attrib = [pos for pos in possibilities if pos[0] == User_input]
              print(getattrib(Account, attrib)) 
         else:
             print("Option not avaliable")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "send user to the action"? How would you give each part of the menu a call number so when the user enters that number it displays the chosen option?

Comment: Send user to action will call the linked function. Eg :  display ID. You can use a list of tuple such as [(0, 'Display ID', display_ID),...] the format is number, name, function. Then you can simply loop trough it, and filter it based on user input.

Comment: Oh, okay. Could you please give me one actual example of the format I have to enter after "If User_Input in possibilities:"? Because it is giving me an account error when I enter a list of tuple.

Comment: @LouisS. This is far from a good implemention but you get it.